# Lipchitz continuity of $f(y) = \exp(y/\alpha)$

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function, lipschitz-functions

Let $y \in [0,M]$ where $M$ is a positive constant and $\alpha > 0$.

Since $y \rightarrow \exp(y)$ is $C^1$ on the compact domain $[0,M]$, then it is Lipchitz and we can write that
$$ |\exp(y_1) - \exp(y_2)| \leq L |y_1-y_2| \forall y_1, y_2 \in [0,M]$$
Now, I'm wondering if we could say a similar thing for the function $y \rightarrow \exp(y/\alpha)$, that is
$$ |\exp(y_1/\alpha) - \exp(y_2/\alpha)| \leq L_{\alpha} |y_1-y_2| \forall y_1, y_2 \in [0,M]$$
When $\alpha \geq 1$, I know that $(y_1/\alpha)$ and $(y_2/\alpha)$ belong to $[0,M]$, then we have
$$ |\exp(y_1/\alpha) - \exp(y_2/\alpha)| \leq L |y_1-y_2| \forall y_1, y_2 \in [0,M]$$

I'm trying to see if this holds for the case when $\alpha < 1$. Intuitively, when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, I think that $|\exp(y_1/\alpha) - \exp(y_2/\alpha)| \sim  0$ since the arguments will be dominated by the term $1/\alpha$ (not quite sure though), so in this case, I think the inequality should also hold.

However, if $\alpha <1$ but not very small (i.e. approaching zero), can we say something?

Comment: Apply Mean Value Theorem. BTW, continuous functions on compact domains need not be Lipschitz.

Comment: It's not true that continuous function on compact are Lipschitz... Take for exemple $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$... However, indeed, $\mathcal C^1$ function on compact are Lipschitz.

Comment: A differentiable function with bounded derivative  is Lipchitz. (Apply LMVT)

Comment: @Surb: I modified the statement now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @geetha290krm: could you elaborate more on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy Do you know the proof of your claim : $y\to \exp{y}$ is $\mathcal{C^1}$ , hence Lipchitz?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I see your point. That resolves the issue, thanks!